# Se puede utilizar el nombre de una columna como condicion en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy recibiendo unos parametros que me dejan la siguiente consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer un `UPDATE` en la columna MONTO_ENE_18, es posible que en mi consulta se pueda agregar el nombre de la columna para que pueda hacer el `UPDATE`?

Comment: Podrias aclarar un poco tu pregunta? el nombre de la columna debe ir en un update.

Comment: Eso es lo que trato de buscar, necesito que la consulta solo me regrese la columna MONTO_ENE_18, para hacerle un UPDATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías dar mas información acerca de como estas intentando hacer la consulta?

Si lo que quieres es actualizar ese valor que tienes señalado sería algo como

```
UPDATE nombretabla  SET MONTO_ENE_18 = 40000 WHERE MONTO_ENE_18 = 30382
```

También podrías utilizar un AND para refinar la búsqueda.

Answer (score 1):

Para actualizar un registro debes hacer uso de **UPDATE**, a continuación la tabla que deseas, luego haces uso de **SET** para especificar que campos deseas actualizar, y al final **WHERE** para aplicar la condición (que filtros se deben cumplir). Ej:

```
UPDATE [Tabla1]
SET columna1 = 'valor', columna2 = 'valor2'
WHERE columna1 = 'condicion' and columna4 = 'condicion'
```

Espero haberte ayudado en tu pregunta, saludos.